$gte for dates works in MongoDB Atlas, but not in Mongoose
I'm trying to query for products that are still on sale using this schema and filter:
// Model
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  sale: {
    until: Schema.Types.Date
  }
})

const Products = model('product', ProductSchema)

// Document
{
  sale: {
    until: "2024-08-18T05:59:00.000Z"
  }
}

// Query
Products.find({ 'sale.until': { $gte: new Date() } })

This always gives me an empty array in Mongoose. If I console log the filter and then paste it into Atlas however, it works just fine. What am I missing from this?
For reference, Mongoose is able to query that field just fine; if I write { 'sale.until': { $exists: false } }, it will correctly give me documents that don't have this sub-property.

You make yoy schema with a Date type. That's correct. But are you sure you are storing Date types also? Even if you define your schema, you can save anything into your collection, and you won't be abble to search with your query if you are not storing dates

As per the sample document provided you are storing date in string format. Make sure that "util" field is stored as ISO Date string in mongodb.
